# require 'watir-webdriver' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, watir

I am trying to use Watir with Rails, and installed it, and when I use it from irb, it works fine. But when I try to include it in rails application, as

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
```

I get the following error:

```
LoadError (no such file to load -- watir-webdriver)
```

Some people had experienced the same problem, which was solved by using require 'rubygems', butin my case, the problem still persists. Any idea?

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: Did you verify that watir-webdriver is installed as a gem? Maybe you could check that with "gem list" to be sure. Also, do you have more than one ruby installed?

Comment: The problem actually was some configuration issues I guess, having multiple ruby versions. I have uninstall everything and installed them back, and it work now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add gem 'watir-webdriver' to your Gemfile in Rails root folder?