# Save screenshot with Watir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir, watir-webdriver, safariwatir

I am using Watir with Ruby on Rails.

I need to save screenshots of couple of pages using Watir. I have managed to get the page that I want to open to show in a browser, but cannot save the screenshot yet. Here's my code:

```
@browser = Watir::Safari.new
folios_screenshot_path = Rails.root.join('screenshots/')
@page = Page.find(5)
cur_url = root_url + 'pages/' + @page.id.to_s
@browser.goto cur_url
@browser.div(:id => "page").wait_until_present
@browser.driver.save_screenshot(pagess_screenshot_path + '/' + @page.id.to_s + '.png')
@browser.close
```

In the page that I load, there's a div element with id 'page', and I am trying to make Watir wait till that element is loaded in the Watir browser. But in my main browser, I get the error **Unable to load page within 10 seconds**, and the screenshot doesn't get saved either. Any idea on what's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

There are several watir gems: watir (drives IE on windows), safariwatir (drives safari on mac), watir-webdriver (drives all popular browsers except safari on all popular operating systems).

You are using safariwatir gem, but you are trying to save screenshot using watir-webdriver's `driver.save_screenshot`. I would suggest that you take a screen shot with Firefox.

Just install watir-webdriver gem and change

```
@browser = Watir::Safari.new
```

to

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
```

For more information, read free version of my Watir book:

https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/downloads

Comment: I looked into the file safariwatir.rb and found that it does not have the driver method in the Browser class, required for taking screenshots. I have been trying to use watir-webdriver instead, but I just cannot include it in my program. Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365555/require-watir-webdriver-error. Thanks for trying to help me out. Please let me know if you can help on this.

Comment: I took a look at your other question, but I have no idea how Rails works, so I can not help there.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem. I read somewhere that, not being able to include a gem, might be because I have multiple versions of ruby installed in my machine. So I removed everything and reinstalled everything and it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try following browser class, it works for me.

```
Browser::BROWSER.driver.save_screenshot(screenshot)
```

([reference](http://watirmelon.com/2011/08/04/capturing-screenshots-in-watir-webdriver-cucumber/))